# Is it possible to download file chunk by chunk without loading into the browser memory

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stream, base64, chunks

I am retrieving a file in chunks from the server and downloading it to the system. The server response is in XML format with a buffer. To manage file size, I receive data in chunks, load it into browser memory, and then initiate the file download. However, for larger files, this approach leads to browser crashes due to memory exhaustion. I'm exploring alternatives to download the file without loading all the chunks into browser memory.

```xml
<Request>
  <Function>cloud::readFile</Function>
  <ArgList>
    <Argument name="fileHandle">open-file-handle</Argument>
    <Argument name="size">number-of-bytes-to-read</Argument>
  </ArgList>
</Request>
```

and the response looks like this

```xml
    
<Response>
  <Status>error-code</Status>
  <StatusMessage>error-message</StatusMessage>
  <ResultList>
    <Result name="status">status-value</Result>
    <Result name="buffer">buffer-in-base64</Result>
    <Result name="size">number-of-bytes-read</Result>
  </ResultList>
</Response>
```

loop through the file size in a while loop and, fetch the data, until all chunks are received, and then I perform download operation

like this

```js
const a = document.createElement('a')
a.href = formatBase64Link(combinedResponse) // base 64 encoded file buffer
a.download = name
a.click()
```

Any insights or suggestions on troubleshooting and resolving this problem would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: why not just initiqate a file download rather than processing it in javascript - since you'll always have to download the whole thing into the browser before being able to process it - how big is the file anyway?

Comment: yes, you're absolute right, I did because, the I thought it is possible to store the chunk outside of the chrome memory, so I can store it there and download it, but seems like, we don't have that ability in front-end, since security reason

now I am thinking alternative solution for this, file size can be anything, 1GB, 2GB, 5GB so on